# Differences between this.prototype and module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As I am new to `Node.js` I am looking for some info, coding some testing stuff and also reading some other people's code.

I've seen that creating/requiring(using) modules is typical in `Node.js`. I've seen different ways of defining "public" methods and function inside modules and both seem to work the same way too:

- `module.exports`
- `this.prototype`

Is there a notable difference by using one or another? Or are just different ways of doing the same thing? Is any of these two better, or it depends on the context?

Comment: Never once seen `this.prototype` used to define a module. You should always follow the methods defined in the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: @BenFortune I found `this.prototype` while reading some other people's code. Have a look to [this code](https://github.com/ttezel/twit/blob/master/examples/bot.js)

Comment: There is no `this.prototype` in the code you linked to...

Comment: @BenFortune also found this too the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: @mscdex there is... lines: 14, 26, 49

Comment: @charliebrownie There is a huge difference between `this.prototype` and `variable.prototype`.

Comment: @BenFortune what is the difference?

Comment: @charliebrownie In the case of `variable.prototype`, the `variable` will normally refer to a "constructor" `function`. The `prototype` is the object that each `new` instances of that constructor will inherit properties from. [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4778408)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski so `module.exports` is used to define some properties that every instance of that module will inherit, and `variable.prototype` is to dynamically add/create new functionality *on the fly* to any instance... am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You should use either `exports` to attach properties to the predefined exported object or reassign `module.exports` to your own object. The latter is common when exporting a constructor for example.

```
exports.foo = function() { console.log('Hello world!'); };
exports.add = function(a, b) { return a + b; };

// Then the module might be used like so:
// var mymodule = require('./mymodule');
// mymodule.foo();
// console.log(mymodule.add(1, 9));
```

Or replace the `exports` object:

```
function Foo() {

}

module.exports = Foo;

// then typically users do this in their script:
// var Foo = require('./mymodule');
// var myFoo = new Foo();
```

Comment: Yes, `module.exports` and `exports` are just the same thing right? They are cool explained [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)!

Comment: It's `module.exports`, but yes, they are *initially* the same thing. However `module.exports` allows you to override the exported object as shown in my examples.

Comment: You are right, I spelled it wrong, thanks for pointing it out. Just edited the whole thing. Thanks!